# How to set up mailbox in Exchange

Tags: exchange-2007

I am new to exchange 2007, but urgently need to create a mailbox for user. This user already exist in AD.

From Exchange Management Console, I find Recipient Configuration > Mailbox > right click > New mail box and follow through to create the mailbox for my existing user, the mailbox created is under Email Adresses is user@company.com.

But I want to create the user under user@alt-company.com.

To attempt, from the Email Addesses tab for the Mailbox property dialog, I "Add..." an SMTP email user@alt-company.com and set it to default reply email. But when I send the from gmail.com to that email, exchange reports 550 user not found.

Also another aside, deleting that mailbox ALSO deletes my existing user!! That is totally irritating, how to avoid that?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but is it the case the Exchange is managing mail for the "alt-company.com" domain too? What happens when you try to send mail _from_ the new mailbox to Gmail?

Comment: @Handyman5 I'm probably dumber than your question. But, we already have existing users who are sending/receiving from alt-company.com. That guy who manages it left the company. Now I am stuck wondering how he did his settings.

Comment: How about sending from the newly-created alt-company.com mailbox? Does that succeed?

Comment: @Handyman5 on the other hand, if you can tell where to set Exchange to handle alt-company.com, i can check and confirm if it is indeed set correctly.

Comment: This document will explain how to set up "accepted domains": [Configure Exchange 2007 to Receive E-Mail for other Domains](http://www.petri.co.il/configure-exchange-2007-recieve-email-other-domains.htm)

Comment: @Handyman5 To answer your questions, I can send email from exhange/outlook 2007 (user@alt-company.com) to gmail.com and other test addresses. I now also realise that the MX may have been set to the postini servers. Any chance you know if I also need to add an entry in Postini?

Comment: @Jake let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/838/discussion-between-handyman5-and-jake)

Comment: @Jake: Yes, you have to create the user at Postini, otherwise Postini (using the default settings) will drop email that's sent to any user that doesn't exist in your Postini configuration.

Comment: @joeqwerty I managed to get postini fixed. Could you kindly add your reply as answer please? Thanks.

Comment: @Jake: Consider it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the user at Postini, otherwise Postini (using the default settings) will drop email that's sent to any user that doesn't exist in your Postini configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This may have changed with Exchange 2007 but in 2000/2003 the mailbox is created from within Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC), not from Exchange Server Management. Also from within ADUC you can set the account's email address(es).

Comment: Can I ask how do I do that? You mean just setting the Email Address field in the user object property?

Comment: @Jake, unless you've installed the Exchange extensions on another machine you'll need to do this on the Exchange server itself. (I'm assuming this remains essentially the same on 2007 as it is on 2003.) In ADUC, right-click the user account and select "Exchange Tasks", followed by "Create Mailbox" and run through the wizard. Once the mailbox has been created you can set the email addresses for the account by opening its properties and selecting the "E-mail Addresses" tab. From there add SMTP addresses as required.

Comment: No "Exchange Tasks" at all in ADUC. I think it's essentially the same doing on the EMC itself.

Comment: @John since exchange 2007, Microsoft stopped extending ADUC and it is now done using the EMC/PowerShell.

Comment: @Jake, looks like you can ignore everything I've said.